# Generate build report with Vite

Tags: npm, vue-cli, vite

Using Vue-CLI I was able to generate a report to analyze the bundle content like this:

```
`npm run build -- --report`
```

I'm now switching to Vite, and I'm wondering if there is a similar command that can create the same report.

Comment: The closest thing is a CLI summary with `rollup-plugin-analyzer`.

Answer (score 5):

As @tony19 mentioned, there is a tool called [rollup-plugin-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-analyzer) which generates a report, including metrics about the modules that make up your bundle.

Note that this isn't actually a Vite tool. It's a rollup plugin that is used during Vite's rollup production build.

First, install the analyzer:

```
npm install rollup-plugin-analyzer --save-dev
```

Include the plugin in the rollup section in your `vite.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import analyze from "rollup-plugin-analyzer";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [analyze()]
    },
  },
});
```

When you run your build (`npm run build`) you will see the report printed to stdout.
Here is a small snippet of what the report looks like so you know what to look for:
[image]